# Who gets the correct solution check?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, up-votes

I submitted a question on Stack Overflow and when I went back to check answers I saw two. I immediately saw two answers, but the first one which happens to be more detailed and a better explanation (to some degree).

I checked that one as the correct solution. I saw the other person's solution, and it is also correct. He commented to me that he was first.

I want to clarify in a thread where there are multiple right answers. Should whomever's first get the correct solution or whomever is better explained when the next person comes?

Question: *[jQuery-mobile popup won't appear at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830168/jquery-popup-wont-appear-at-all?noredirect=1#comment65032684_38830168)*

Comment: See also: [Etiquette for selecting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19448/21960)

Comment: See also: [Which answer do I accept if I have multiple correct answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13396/21960)

Answer (score 3):

You accept whichever answer **you** want to.

You don't have to explain it.

The consensus is - the better answer should get it, but it is entirely up to you.